# No Kenai on NetBeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

In NetBeans 6.7 Kenai, can be found in the menu bar Team > Kenai > Get Samples but in NetBeans 8.0 there is no such thing, is there anyway I can find this option in Netbeans 8.0?

Answer (score 1):

`Tools | Plugins | Available Plugins` and look for Kenai there. Then you can install support for kenai.

BTW: `kenai.com` is basically dead which is a good things because as a project hosting it sucked and was only promoted by Sun/Oracle projects.